# R counting occurrence of string

Tags: r

I have read data from multiple xlsx sheet with xlsx package of R. Currently my data frame is like below

```
 firstcol                               SecondCol
 A                                       abcd
 B                                       bds
 A                                       <NA>
 A                                       asd
 C                                       <NA>
 B                                       adfdf
 ?                                       <NA>
 C                                       adfd
```

From the above data I want to get the following output.

```
Firsrcol  FirstcolCount         SecondCol
A           3 times              2       # we'll not count NA's  
B           2 times              2
C           2 times              1
other       1 times              0
```

Is there any direct method that can do this? It would be nice to have some suggestion about this.

Comment: Just need a bit more clues, can you run an `str(yourDataFrameName)` and copy the results into the question above? Thanks

Comment: in base r, the convoluted: `merge(data.frame(table(DT$x[!is.na(DT$x)])),data.frame(table(DT$x[!is.na(DT$y)])), by = "Var1")` might work

Comment: thanks @Chris for your help. its fastest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though not quite clear what exactly you mean. Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(firstcol) %>% summarise(FirstcolCount = n(), SecondCol = n() - sum(SecondCol == "<NA>"))
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

  firstcol FirstcolCount SecondCol
1        ?             1         0
2        A             3         2
3        B             2         2
4        C             2         1
```

Comment: Sorry which package gives %>%?

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` approach:

```
#load library
require(data.table)

# convert data.frame to data.table
setDT(df)

# make a new data.table with two columns. First one has the counts by each level of firstcol. Second one has the count minus the number of NA cases:
df[, .(FirsrcolCount = .N, 
       secondCol = .N - sum(is.na(secondcol))), 
     by = firstcol]
```